# Check if a process is running in 64 or 32-bit mode?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, process

I'd like to check if a process is running in 64-bit or 32-bit mode.  How can I do this?  Process Explorer will tell me if the Image is 32-bit or 64-bit, is this what I should be looking at?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you can identify this by the Image Type in Process Explorer.

Comment: 'Image Type (64 vs 32-bit)' on the 'Process Image' tab in Process Explorer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can we assume this is a Windows question? XP x64, Vista, 7?

In Windows 7 I believe a 32-bit application running in a 64-bit OS has a `*32` after its name in the Task Manager...

[image: Windows 7 Task Manager]

Answer (score 28):

## No need 3rd party programs !

Open `Task Manager > Details`, right click on columns bar `Select Columns`  and check `Platform`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

*(Windows 10 and 8)*

Comment: This should be at the top.

Answer (score 21):

Just to add to this old answer, yes use Process Explorer. You can right click on the columns and select Image Type to show which processes are 32 bit and which are 64 bit. Run Process as Administrator to see some services.

http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe

[image]

Comment: How do you know the bitness of the process I selected on https://i.imgur.com/QBwqToN.png ?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Windows 7 task manager where 32-bit processes are shown with `*32`, in Windows 8 and 10 they'll be shown with `(32 bit)` at the end. No need to go to the Details tab and add another column!

[image: Task manager]

In compact mode they're shown in the same way, but in less detail compared to the Processes tab and Details tab

[image: Compact task manager]

See [Windows 8 Task Manager In-Depth](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2013/06/06/windows-8-task-manager-in-depth/)